# login with linked in static key works but dynamic php key does not work

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am implementing login with linked in javascript SDK.

I am passing the app id dynamically(from the database). When I pass the key static, the linked in button works but when I pass the same key from the database, it does not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var linkedin_api_id = "<?php echo LINKEDIN_APP_ID; ?>";
    alert(linkedin_api_id); //displays correct key
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: linkedin_api_id //here static key works but passing variable does not work
    authorize: false
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
    scope: r_basicprofile r_emailaddress
</script>
```

And code to display button:

```
<script type="in/Login"></script> <!--this displayed when key passed statically but does not displayed when passed the same key from database-->
```

Comment: bcz its start loading before the key from the database, load it once the key is assign

Comment: try only this 

    `<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
     api_key: "<?php echo LINKEDIN_APP_ID; ?>"
     authorize: false
     onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
     scope: r_basicprofile r_emailaddress
    </script>`

Comment: ohh, i have already tried this, but it did not worked so i tried this one to check whether key coming from database is correct/loading or not.